# Vue.js components hierarchical relationship

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is there a native way or something to figure it out if two components are hierarchically related?

> - Parent 1
>
>   - Child 1
>
>     - Grand child 1
>     - Grand child 2
>   - Child 2
> - Parent 2

Let's say I want to check wether `Parent 1` and `Grand child 1` are related.

I could access their `vNode instance` and make a recursive search, but it doesn't seem to be that way.

```js
const areVNodeRelated = (parent, child) => {
    parent.$children.forEach(comp => {
        if (comp === child) {
            return true
        }
        return areVNodeRelated(comp, child)
    })

    return false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is are at least 2 native approaches of figuring out if a DOM node is a parent of another node:

1.This one is cross-browser and it implies using the [DOMNode.parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode)

```
function isChildOf(parent, child) {
     const node = child.parentNode;
     while (node) {
         if (node == parent) {
             return true;
         }
         node = node.parentNode;
     }
     return false;
}
```

2.Much more elegant way is to use directly the [DOMNode.contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) method. This returns directly a boolean.

```
parentNode.contains(childNode);
```

That was in pure JavaScript, but in Vue you will have to use the `refs` property to get the node and then just to the same as above. 
So the code can be something along this lines:

```
<template>
  <div id="app" ref="app">
    <HelloWorld msg="Hello Vue!" ref="hello"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
  mounted() {
    // Note: the root is directly a DOM element.
    const appNode = this.$refs.app;
    const helloNode = this.$refs.hello.$el;

    console.log(this.containsChild(appNode, helloNode)); // TRUE
  },
  methods: {
    containsChild(parent, child) {
      return parent.contains(child);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Indeed, the second method looks cleaner, but it requires to define a `refs` value as you said. I would rather not in my case, so I will stick to the first method. I can see now that I was doing it in the wrong sens: `from parent to child`, instead of `child to parent`. Thank you.